# How to handle many models and queryset in a single template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I don't know how can I access to multiple models in a single template? in other words, what kind of queryset or template code do I have to use?

In my case, I have 3 models: first, Lead, which concerns lead informations, second is leadstatus, which talks about where lead were found and third actions to do with him.

in a kind of contact-list view where I use a function `def contactList(request):`. My goal is to display, in an array, some of the information about this lead, about his status, and about the last action to do with him. So, what kind of queryset do I have to write in the view or what kind of code do I have to use in the template?

SO here is my models.py:

```
class Lead (models.Model):
 #this model only takes private and personal items from the contact
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
firstname  = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='adresse email',
    max_length=255, 
    unique=True,
)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True )

FAMILY_SITUATION = [
    ("Celib", "Celib"),
    ("Couple", "Couple"),
    ("Veuf", "Veuf"),
]

familySituation = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=FAMILY_SITUATION, blank=True, null=True )
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

class LeadStatus(models.Model):
lead = models.OneToOneField(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
leadsource = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )#ou est ce que je l'ai trouvé 
traditionalSeller = models.BooleanField(default=False)#vendeur dans le traditionnel
traditionalBuyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)#acheteur dans le traditionnel
businessProvider =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
INTEREST_TO_SERVICE = [
    ("inconnu", "inconnu"),
    ("non-intéréssé", "non-intéréssé"),
    ("suspect", "suspect"),
    ("prospect", "prospect"),
    ("client", "client"),
    ("super-client", "super-client"),
]
interest = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=INTEREST_TO_SERVICE, blank=True, null=True ) #[inconnu, non-intéréssé, suspect (pourrait être intéressé), prospect, client]
lastUpdated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.lead

class ActionWithLead (models.Model):
lead = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name =  models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my template.html:

```
<tbody>
   {% for contact in contacts %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{contact.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.city}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.created}}</td>
                    <!-- lead status information-->
                    <td>{{status}}</td>
                    <td>{{traditionnelBuyer}}</td>
                    <td>{{businessProvider}}</td>
                    <td>{{interest}}</td>
                    <td>{{created}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: A `User` can be related to multiple `Lead`s?

Comment: Yess a user can have multiple leads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `contact` is a `Lead` object, you can access the related `LeadStatus` object with:

```
<tbody>
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ contact.lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.created }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.leadstatus.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.leadstatus.traditionnelBuyer }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.leadstatus.businessProvider }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.leadstatus.interest }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.leadstatus.created }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, it is unclear why you have a `LeadStatus` model, and do not just store the `LeadStatus` data in the `Lead` model.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `traditionnel_buyer` instead of <s>`traditionnelBuyer`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Idk why I found more clear for me to have another model but you are right. 

So my second question is how can I access to my actionWithLead model in my template and in my loop? It’s related to the lead model with foreign key. 

Thank you,  i will use _ and setting.auth…